# VSCODE integration of debugging Raspberry Pico with Debug probe. On MacOS host platform not able to configure

Tags: macos, debug, vs-code

I asked the same question in stackoverflow.com but it may be more appropriate to ask this question here:

I have been pulling my hair out trying to configure VSCode on MacOS to support the debugging of a Raspberry Pico with the debug probe.
I have debugging working on the command line: I started the OpenOCD server in a separate terminal window like this:

**sudo openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -c "adapter speed 5000"**

Which starts fine and recognises the debug probe.

In a terminal window within VSCode I select the PICO examples build/blink directory and I start the debugger:

**arm-none-eabi-gdb blink.elf**

and I can happily set breakpoints etc. So the basic setup works, and the targets built by VSCode are proper.

However, to get visual debugging within the GUI fails. I have tried various variations of 'launch.json', 'settings.json' and 'tasks.json' but none seem to work.

The variations I found on the various sites are all similar, but none of them are functional. I also tried variations of json files in the 'ide/vscode' as distributed but no succes..

I am using VSCode Version on MacOS Monterey 12.6.7:
VSCODE 1.79.2 (Universal) Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:58:52.392Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1 V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0

Does anybody have this working on a system similar to mine? If so, what are the settings in the json files.

I did install OpenOCD for MacOS (chipcode-nl.picoprobe-mac) as well, but that does not seem to be very functional. As I explained above, the basic setup for OpenOCD from the command line works...